# Authentication error while accessing WSO2 EMM agent

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot, wso2-identity-server

While using WSO2 EMM agent on my android device I get this error

> cannot process the authentication.please contact administrator.

Can anybody please help my how to resolve this error.

Comment: Please provide more details, error trace and the scenario when the error occurred.

Comment: I run the wso2 emm server and then in my  device i downloaded the wso2 agent app, then i am trying to sign in but it is giving the above error.The credentials which i entering are the same whiich i entered in the emm web , through adding user

Comment: Hey Kachiecx, please do help to resolve this issue

Comment: Yeah i will do can you provide the tenant of he user you have created and the domain you have provided with the logins if you can edit the Question and include stack trace from the server side if there are any issues it will be very helpful

Comment: Any updates on this ???

Comment: Hey @ Kachiex  sorry for the late reply, the problem was resolved,actually my port was blocked and i have not done proper email configurations, but now i am receiving mails, but now server unavailable error is coming, i think my device and pc are not connected over same network, i.e why this error is coming.

Comment: in order you to get the error mentioned in this question device needs to be connected with the server. can you make sure when you are enrolling the device use http://<IP>:9763 (if you are using default setting in the ports) and try again.

Comment: In order to connect to the ip of the server both device and sever need to be connect to the same network this is a must

Comment: while accessing the wso2 agent app server error is still coming, in the first step i have tried all the possible combinations like https://<IP>, http://<IP>,https://<IP>:9443, https://<IP>:9763.But none of them is working .what is the correct format of this server address which i have to enter.

Comment: Use this format http://<IP>:9763 . make sure to use HTTP . and make sure both server and device are in the same network or the server is hosted in server with public static IP.